# (Vowpal Wabbit) Contextual bandit simulation error

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit

I'm using vowpal wabbit to simulate and evaluate offline my model. So I used the functions that was present in the tutorial section in the website https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/cb_simulation.html.

I got an error when I run the model.

the error is :       `cb_adf: badly formatted example, only one line can have a cost`

So I printed the format to see if its really the case but for me the format was ok since I got this format just before the error pop-up :

```
shared |User client=1425 ord_amt=69.90674997927502 PM=24.676111110999997
|Action actions=0 
|Action actions=1 
|Action actions=2 
|Action actions=3 
|Action actions=4 
|Action actions=5 
0:44.83788:0.82222 |Action actions=6 
|Action actions=7 
|Action actions=8
```

Moreover this error pop-up always in the 16-th iteration my users are picked randomly in each run that I  made.

Some one have faced the same error or someone can point me in the direction of a solution ?

Comment: This looks to be a bug, sorry you've hit this. Can you please open this as an [issue on the repo?](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/issues/new/choose) Please include the code you ran exactly. 

I think this is fixed and will be patched in 8.8.1, but I would like to confirm.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much for saving my time :D, I don't know if I can share my code because of share rules constraint in my company ! But thank you so much for lighting me !

Comment: Hello @jackgerrits, I am facing the same problem, I cannot easily update the code and the data but if you tell me which branch contain the patch I can try and check if things are working now.

Comment: This commit should be the fix: https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/commit/431c270742e76c7524413c33e76e47851cba549e Let me know if it helps or doesn't